# Can we use multiple nested levels inside a projection with the MongoDB c# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Imagine we have the following classes in c#7, dotnet core 3.1, corresponding to data stored inside a MongoDB collection:

```
public class Level1
{
    public string Field1 {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Level2> Next1 {get; set;}
}

public class Level2
{
    public string Field2 {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Level3> Next2 {get; set;}
}

public class Level3
{
    public string Field3 {get; set;}
    public string Field4 {get; set;}
}
```

For optimization reasons, we want to retrieve Field3 but not Field4, and all the data of Level1 & Level2. (of course this is a simplification: there are a lot of data we actually want to ignore in the real case).

For this, the usual way in Mongo is to use a projection. It works perfectly with JSON queries like `find({}, {"Field1": 1, "Next1.Field2": 1, "Next1.Next2.Field3": 1})`. We get the full object hierarchy, but with Field4 missing, i.e. exactly what we want.

However, I am stuck when trying to do this in c# using a recent version of the official driver. I could obviously just use the raw JSON query and it would work - but I would miss all the goodness of the driver-managed mapping, such as field names following refactorings. So we want to use expressions.

I have tried this :

```
var result = db.GetCollection<Level1>("mycollection")
    .Find("{}")
    .Project(Builders<Level1>.Projection.Expression(p => new Level1
    {
        Field1 = p.Field1,
        Next1 = p.Next1.Select(s => new Level2
        {
            Field2 = s.Field2,
            Next2 = s.Next2.Select(r => new Level3
            {
                Field3 = r.Field3,
            },
        },
    }));
```

This however generates the following unexpected JSON:

```
find({}
}, {
    "Field1": 1,
    "Next2.Field3": 1,
    "Next1.Next2": 1,
    "Next1.Field2": 1
})
```

and of course, this means that Field4 is not filtered - the projection is just wrong. It seems to only work on two levels, and to stop prefixing the projection clauses after two levels.

Would you know if there is a possibility to do what I want with an expression? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have opened a case at MongoDB and they have confirmed it is a bug on their side, referenced [on their JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-3227)

There is no known workaround using an object expression, so we are using Include() for now and will update when the driver is fixed.